# adp devices not recognizing my HTC Desire 616

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating a simple android app using cordova (windows 8 using Netbeans) , few testing I need to do on my phone which is HTC 616. I am unable to find this device on running 'adb devices'. I tried a few solutions but could not get it working.
Couple of things that I tried were:

1. I tried adding this code to android_winusb.inf file
   %SingleAdbInterface%, %CompositeAdbInterface%
   and to file adb_usb.ini I added the following code
   0x
2. Also tried downloading and installing HTC Sync, but didn't get further steps I just installed it

Noe of these solutions worked for me, I had contacted HTC support but could not any positive response from them. Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: You do know that it is `adb` and not `adp` right? Have you checked that the correct drivers are installed?

Comment: Ya, it was just a typing mistake... there are no drivers for the device is the answer I got from HTC support. Few answers claim that the first option I tried will work but not in my case....

Comment: Did you try installing using the drivers that come bundled with the android sdk? See this https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: Yup, USB drivers are already installed and I tried making changes to files andriod_winusb.inf and adb_usb.ini...